# Closed form for the Engel expansion of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For any positive real number $x$,the [Engel expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion) is given by
$$x=\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_1a_2}+\frac{1}{a_1a_2a_3}+...$$
where $a_1,a_2,a_3...$ are the increasing sequence of positive integers. The construction of Engel expansion is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion).

Now the numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3...$ in the Engel expansion for $e$ may be given the closed form as $a_n=n!, n>1$.

Can we have such a closed form Engel series for $\pi$?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A006784

Comment: In the Engel expansion of $\mathrm{e}$, $a_n \neq n!$. $a_1=1$ and $a_n=n-1$ for $n\ge 2$.